# SAS Create Multiple Tables Based on Given Character Elements

Tags: sas

---

**UPDATE** I've been told this isn't possible using arrays because of they way they are stored.  This changes my question a bit, but the gist is still the same.  How can I most efficiently generate the tables I need from a given vector of values (ex: day, week, month, year) without just repeating the code multiple times?  Is there any way to simply substitute the given date value into `INTX` in a loop?

---

Ok, this is my last question on this subject, I promise.  After some good advice, I'm using the `INTX` function.  However, I'd like to just loop through the different categories I select and create tables.  I tried this, but to no avail.

```
data;
    array period [*] $ day week month year;
run;

%MACRO sqlloop;
  proc sql;
    %DO k = 1 %TO dim(&period);  /* in case i decide to drop/add from array later */
      %LET bucket = &period[&k];
      CREATE TABLE output.t_&bucket AS (
        SELECT INTX( "&bucket.", date_field, O, 'E') AS test FROM table);
    %END
  quit;
%MEND
%sqlloop
```

Sadly this doesn't work because I'm fouling up the array reference somehow.  If I can get this step I'll be in good shape.

Comment: You cannot use arrays like that.  Arrays are only inside the data step, they have no meaning outside of the single datastep they are run in.

Comment: Hmm, okay.  I'm so used to doing things in R that the terminology is confusing me.  Is there any way to loop through that PROC SQL using some fixed list of character elements?  Where I could define (day, week, month, year, qtr) etc and then have it create multiple tables?

Comment: I guess I could just copy and paste the code for each of the, but it seems like there has to be some way that I'm not seeing.  In R, I would just make a vector and run _n_ loops for each element, substituting it into the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your array with a macro variable string:

```
%let period=day week month year;
```

In your macro then, you loop over the words in the macro variable:

```
%MACRO sqlloop;
  proc sql;
    %DO k = 1 %TO %sysfunc(countw(&period.)); /*fixed extra s*/
      %LET bucket = %scan(&period.,&k.);
      CREATE TABLE output.t_&bucket AS (
        SELECT INTNX( "&bucket.", date_field, 0, 'E') AS test FROM table);
    %END;
  quit;
%MEND;
%sqlloop
```

*edit* you forgot some semicolons apparently. :p

Comment: Thanks Shorack.  That totally makes sense.  I've worked in R for so long that I'm having a lot of trouble adapting but this is really helping.  This should help me get through this current project while I keep studying.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that i've corrected some last minute typo's and other silly mistakes i've made. Make sure you don't copy them along.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine, I have trouble transcribing the code sometimes and leave things out because I am under a weird copy-paste prevention scheme so it's hard to just plop in the right code and I have to enter everything twice.  Thanks again!